# Render JSON response using Django's render()

Tags: python, json, django, mediafire

I am working my way through Django's tutorial but failing to display an API response using Django's render() function.

**models.py**

```
...
class MF_Version():
    def get_MF_Version(self):
        url = 'https://www.mediafire.com/api/1.5/system/get_version.php?response_format=json'
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r
...
```

**views.py**

```
...
def view_Version(request):
    hr = HttpResponse(MF_Version().get_MF_Version())
    return render(request, 'mediafire/version.html', {'hr': hr})
    # return hr
...
```

**version.html**

```
{% if 1 %}
    {{ hr }}
{% endif %}
```

**Browser output:**

```
&lt;HttpResponse status_code=200, &quot;text/html; charset=utf-8&quot;&gt;
```

**MefiaFire response:**

```
{"response":{"action":"system\/get_version","current_api_version":"1.5","result":"Success"}}
```

If I comment out `return render(...)` in the view.py file and replace it with `return hr`, I do see the JSON response from MediaFire, but I cannot figure out how to access `action`, `current_api_version` and `result` in the HTML template.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/), which is available since Django 1.7

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def view_Version(request):
    return JsonResponse(MF_Version().get_MF_Version())
```

You don't need render at all.

If you need render write it as follows (untested):

```
{% for x in hr %}
    {{ x }}: {{ hr.x }}
{% endfor %}
```

and your python code will look like:

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def view_Version(request):
    hr = JsonResponse(MF_Version().get_MF_Version())
    return render(request, 'mediafire/version.html', {'hr': json.loads(hr)})
```

Comment: I need to use render().

Comment: any luck with this? pls. accept an answer or provide your own

Answer (score 0):

`MF_Version().get_MF_Version()` get a json,

you can try this:

```
def view_Version(request):
    hr = MF_Version().get_MF_Version().json()
    return render(request, 'mediafire/version.html', {'hr': hr}
```

Comment: That outputs : &lt;HttpResponse status_code=200, &quot;text/html; charset=utf-8&quot;&gt;